# Java unable to compile and run class

Tags: java, javac, executable-jar

when I go to the directory which contains the .java class, which in turn contains the main() method, and run `javac Application.java`, I get this error:
[image]

And then when I run java `Application.java` just to see the output, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Application.java
```

Apparently it doesn't even recognize the class there.

This is the output of `java -version`:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

This is the output of `javac -version`:

```
javac 1.8.0_45
```

Not really sure what's wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you try to execute from the command line, you have to use `java Application`. No file type is used here. - The screenshot with the howto you've included does contain the correct form!

Comment: Starting with an app using Spring is very audacious. Try some Hello-World and proceed from that.

Comment: Seems that you download some github project and is trying to compile one class through command line. The best approach is import it to an IDE because it use 3rd part libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not managing to compile your application is that you're importing classes from elsewhere, but you've not told the compiler where to find those classes. You need to add them to the class path for the compiler. In this case, you're importing some classes from the Spring framework, but you haven't supplied the relevant `.jar` files to the compiler so that it knows where to find the classes you're importing.

The second error you get is when you try to run your program, but you can't because you haven't managed to generate a compiled version.

I would very strongly recommend that you download Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA or a similar IDE, and use that for your development and compilation. It will handle pretty much all of this for you. You have a painful road ahead of you if you want to compile from the command line.

Comment: Agreed.  For Java learners, the popular IDE's abstract away all (or most) of the build script complexity.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because I need to write a bash script for my docker container that starts a java application.

Comment: I've used Eclipse for 2 years and really had no clue how to compile java classes through the command line because of it.

Comment: If you've used Eclipse for 2 years and are now writing a multi-module application that requires build management ... then you probably really are wanting Maven.  I recommend that you invest the time needed to learn to use it.  There is a serviceable tutorial at http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/

Comment: @Ikshvaku do you need to compile inside the docker container, though, or just run it? You're better off compiling outside the container to produce an executable `jar` file, and then running the self-contained `jar` from inside the container.

Comment: @chaistic-security, Yeah that actually sounds like a better idea. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your application is using some 3rd party libraries like Spring. You need to tell java where to find these libraries. You can copy them somewhere and refer to them by the classpath configuration. To make things simpler, look into maven - dependency management system.

Comment: *"To make things simpler, look into maven..."* ... it depends on what you mean by simpler.  To people that know Maven, its use is natural.  For those to whom Maven is unknown, it presents a seemingly illimitable landscape of obfuscation and complexity.

Comment: It is much simpler to use maven than to put the right jars into the right place and correctly configure the classpath. for beginners it is simpler. You just copy and paste some xml and it works like magic.

Comment: I'll just assume you're in the former category.  Maven POM hierarchies can become sooooo complex.  People that live with Maven every day just forget how nonintuitive it can look.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you comment you can put all 3rd part jars into some folder and run `javac -cp "<folder_with_jars>" Application.java`.

If there isn't any compile errors it will generate the class file and then you can execute with `java Application`